# Luzin's theorem, finding a continuous function under a certain condition

Tags: general-topology, geometry, measure-theory

Let $X:\mathbb R^2\rightarrow\mathbb R,$ be the map defined by $(x,y)\mapsto y-x.$ Let $h:\mathbb R\rightarrow\mathbb R$ be Borel measurable.  Let $\mu$ be a Borel probability measure on $\mathbb R^2.$ Assume $\mu(h\cdot X\geq 0)=1.$ We think of $h$ as a function from $\mathbb R^2$ to $\mathbb R$ by extending it trivially. I am trying to show that for any $\varepsilon >0$ there exists a continuous function $h':\mathbb R\rightarrow\mathbb R$ such that $\mu(h'X\geq 0)=1$ and $\mu(h'\neq h)<\varepsilon.$

My first attempt was to use Luzin's theorem. By Luzin's theorem, for every $\varepsilon>0$ there exists a compact set $K\subseteq\mathbb R^d$ with $\mu(K^c)<\varepsilon$ such that $h$ restricted to $K$ is continuous. So conditional on $K,$ we have $\mu(hX\geq 0\mid K)=1.$ Further, by Tietze's theorem, we can extend $h1_K$ to a continuous function $h'$ on whole $\mathbb R.$ But generally, this function may fail the property $\mu(h'X\geq 0)=1.$ Thanks in advance for comments/counterexamples...

Answer (score 1):

This cannot be done in general. To clarify the setup, introduce the measures $\mu_+ = \mu \,\chi_{\{X>0\}}$
and $\mu_- = \mu \,\chi_{\{X<0\}}$. Let $\nu_+,\nu_-$ be their pushforwards to $\mathbb R$ under the projection $(x,y)\to x$.
Then the statement becomes:

> Given $h:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ such that $\nu_+(\{h<0\})=0$  and $\nu_-(\{h>0\})=0$, find a continuous function $g$ such that $\nu_+(\{g<0\})=0$,   $\nu_-(\{g>0\})=0$, and
>   $$\nu_{+}(\{h\ne g\}) + \nu_{-}(\{h\ne g\})<\epsilon \tag1$$

Counterexample: let $E=[0,1]$ be a Cantor-type set of positive measure. Let $\nu_+$ and $\nu_-$ be the restrictions of the Lebesgue measure to $E$ and $[0,1]\setminus E$, respectively. Consider $h=\chi_E$.

If $g$ is a continuous function that is positive somewhere on $[0,1]$, then $\nu_-(\{g>0\})>0$, which is not allowed. Therefore, $g\le 0$ on $[0,1]$. But then (1) fails.

You can reassemble these $\nu_+$, $\nu_-$ back into $\mu$ to obtain a counterexample in original setup.

Comment: Is $\mu_{-}$ the push forward of $\mu$ under the map $\chi_{\{X<0\}}$?

Comment: @AndyTeich No, not pushforward, but restriction. Written as multiplication by characteristic function of the set to which the measure is being restricted.